# Absolutely continuity of sample paths of the hitting times of Levy subordinators

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-measure

Let $X_t$ be a strictly increasing Levy subordinator with infinite activity on $\mathbb R$. Consider its first exit time process

$$\tau_t = \inf\{s > 0 :X_s >t \}$$

Since $X_t$ is strictly increasing, $\tau_t$ must be continuous. Also, in the sets $[X_{t-}(\omega), X_t(\omega)]$, $\tau_t(\omega)$ is constant. But then, since $X_t$ is of infinite activity, the set where $\tau_t(\omega)$ is not constant, for almost all $\omega$, contains no intervals.

All in all, the sample paths of $\tau_t
$ look a bit like the devil staricase.

My question at this point would be: are the functions $\tau_t(\omega)$ absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

More in general, can anybody point out at references regarding the path properties of hitting times of Levy processes?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something obvious: Absolutely continuous functions are, in particular, continuous, right? Since $(X_t)_t$ is a jump process, the sample paths cannot be absolutely continuous.

Comment: Absolutely right. Corrected the critical typo.

Comment: For example, when $X_t$ has finite activity (a compound Poisson process), then strictly increasingness means that between jump arrival times the process increases linearly at a rate $b>0$. When considering its inverse process $\tau_t$ the sample path will consist of flat spots, corresponding to jumps in $X_t$, linearly interpolated during the sets corresponing to the inter-arrival times. Therefore in the finite activity case, the paths of  $\tau_t$ are absolutely continuous.

Comment: yeah, sure, now I understand your question.

Comment: If the lebesgue measure of the continuity set of X_t (or equivalently, the set of non constancy of tau_t) can be proved to be 0, then one can use the same "0 derivative argument" as for the Cantor function to show they cannot be absolutely continuous. To add a bit of information, it follows from theorem 21.3 in Sato's book, that the set where the sample paths are non constant is the complementary of the preimage of countable dense set (i.e.  the set where X_t jumps). Still, in principe no relation to measure-theory.

Answer (score 2):

If the infinite-activity subordinator $X_t$ is driftless, then the closed range of $(X_t)$, which coincides with the support of the diffuse measure whose "distribution function" is $(\tau_t)$, is of Lebesgue measure $0$. It follows that $(\tau_t)$ is purely singular. A good reference for this topic is the Saint-Flour lectures of Jean Bertoin *Subordinators: examples and applications*, in the the Springer Lectures in Math. series, volume 1717.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference; I had looked at those notes already but smehow misse the relvant section. It is then my understanding that as a consequence of proposition 1.8 in Bertoin,if  $X_t$ is driftless, $d\tau_t$ is  singular continuous, whereas an absolutely continuous part in the Lesbegue decomposition may arise when a positive drift is present, owing to the support of $d\tau_t$ not having Lebesgue measure 0.